# Missing $ inserted in a logic function

Tags: math-mode, logic

The error appears at this line:

```
\paragraph{ \neg A \wedge (B \vee C) }
```

How do I repair it?

Comment: `\paragraph{$ \neg .... $}`  You need math mode for this

Comment: Hi and welcome to Tex.SE. Could you please provide an MWE (minimal working example) that we can use when trying to help you? With only a single line we can't really say much. The MWE should contain the bare minimum of code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.sx. Since `\neg`, `\wedge` `\vec` are math macros they can't be inside `\paragraph` unless you put enclose them in `\( ... \)` or `$ ... $`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such commands like `\neq` etc. need math mode, i.e. switching into that mode with `$...$` or `\( ...\)`.

'Care' must be taken when `hyperref` is used in conjunction with math mode within arguments of structuring commands like `\section`, `\subsection`, etc, of course `\paragraph` too, if this is to be included into the bookmarks and ToC.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\subsection{First}
\subsubsection{First}

\paragraph{ $\neg A \wedge (B \vee C)$ }

\end{document}
```

[image]